# Dotted Line in top and bottom in iText

Tags: android, itext

I am using iText to generate pdf. I want to draw dotted line in table header.
Now I am trying like this.

```
private void createTable(Document document)  throws DocumentException {
              Report_Page app = new Report_Page();
            float[] columnWidths = { 1.5f, 5f, 2f, 1.5f, 2f };          
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);

            table.setTotalWidth(300f);

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("P.No"));
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setCellEvent(app.new DottedCell());
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            table.addCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Item Name"));
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setCellEvent(app.new DottedCell());
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            table.addCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Price"));
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setCellEvent(app.new DottedCell());
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            table.addCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Qty"));
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setCellEvent(app.new DottedCell());
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            table.addCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ext Price"));
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell.setCellEvent(app.new DottedCell());
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            table.addCell(cell);
            table.setHeaderRows(1);     


        }


class DottedCell implements PdfPCellEvent {

            @Override
            public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
                    PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
                PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
                canvas.setLineDash(3f, 3f);
                canvas.rectangle(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom(),
                    position.getWidth(), position.getHeight());
                canvas.stroke();

            }
        }
```

Now the O/P is like this.
[image: OP Image]

But I want to remove left and right side border from this. Please let me any idea to remove left and right border.

Image for table center:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [DottedLineHeader](https://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/DottedLineHeader) header example. You have copy/pasted code from the [DottedLineCell](https://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/DottedLineCell) and you create a full rectangle instead of two separate lines. Hence the answer to your question could be: draw two lines instead of the four sides of a rectangle:

```
class DottedCell implements PdfPCellEvent {
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
        PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.setLineDash(3f, 3f);
        canvas.moveTo(position.getLeft(), position.getTop());
        canvas.lineTo(position.getRight(), position.getTop());
        canvas.moveTo(position.getLeft(), position.getBottom());
        canvas.lineTo(position.getRight(), position.getBottom());
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

While you may say: *Hey, this works!*, I would feel guilty if you accepted and upvoted such an anwer as it's not the best answer. Why not? Because you would be drawing a separate line for each cell with a different starting point for the first dash of each of these lines.

The better solution would be to define the header rows as header rows (using the `setHeaderRows()` method) and to draw the lines using a table event:

```
class DottedHeader implements PdfPTableEvent {
    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths,
        float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart,
        PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.setLineDash(3f, 3f);
        float x1 = widths[0][0];
        float x2 = widths[0][widths.length];
        canvas.moveTo(x1, heights[0]);
        canvas.lineTo(x2, heights[0]);
        canvas.moveTo(x1, heights[headerRows]);
        canvas.lineTo(x2, heights[headerRows]);
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

In this event you write only two lines for the header instead of a multiple of two lines when you use a cell event.

Comment: Hi @Bruno Lowagie.. Thanks for your valuable answer. 
I will try and let you know shortly..

Comment: Hi @Bruno.. This what I want. :-) But I use your 1st Solution(Sorry).. Because I am very new to iText. Now only I am studying about iText. Have to complete my task with in 3 days. So Don't Mistake me.. And I am trying to center the table. But I can't. I am using **  table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);**. But No luck.. :-(

Comment: Using `table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER)` centers the table horizontally. See http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=77 and take a look at http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter04/table_alignment.pdf (That works, doesn't it?)

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? If I run this exact file, I always get the correct answer. Hence I think you are not using the exact same Java code that can be found here: http://examples.itextpdf.com/src/part1/chapter04/TableAlignment.java

Comment: Sorry Sir. Heavy Confused.. Yesterday I change iText to lowagie. May be this is the problem. I will try with iText and let you know sir. Sorry again and thank you sir.. Sir final question. iText is Open source or not. I am going to develop a application for us. Not for sale. So can I use this iText for free??

Comment: Right Person..!! But Wrong Version..!!(Sorry.. Just joke..).. The link for free book is right one???

Comment: The link to the free ebook is http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html